# importing JSON object with React

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to import a .JSON file however my terminal keeps spitting out this error:

> ERROR in ./src/sampleModel.json Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token, expected ; (2:10)

I am certain there are no JSON syntax errors and for some reason it is expecting a semicolon. I am importing it like so in my project file.

```
import modelSchema from "sampleModel.json";
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Please write the codes and details...

Comment: Post the json file code please

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: The mistake can be in a build system that you use or in invalid JSON file. Give us more information.

Comment: is your `sampleModel.json` just a JSON object? That might not work. You might need to export it with `module.exports = {...the json}` for example